# Which is the best way to detect function call patterns in file

Tags: php, regex, string

I've the next code in a string:

```
<div class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <span class="text-muted my-2 my-sm-0 mx-2">@lang('Welcome, user', ['user'=> $user]). {{ $login }} {!! $adminBadge !!}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" role="button">@lang('menu.close_session')</a>@lang('This is a very @lang("gag") complex string') another {{ __('call example') }} call
        </div>
```

The question is taht I want to get all the string contained on each `@lang()` and `__()` and I don't know how is the best way to get, with regexp it doesn't work fine with the next pattern: `@lang\('([^']+)'\)` due this will fail on `@lang('something\'asohgag')` or `@lang('Another faled \'string\'oagha')`
How can I fix this ensuring all @lang calls are checked successfully?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, thanks to the web https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/regex-quoted-string-escapable-quotes, I've discovered how to detect a string with includins escaping quotes inside:
The resulting code is the next:

```php
$reStringPattern = "((?<![\\\\])['\"])((?:.(?!(?<![\\\\])\\1))*.?)\\1";

if(preg_match_all("/@lang\({$reStringPattern}(,[^\)]+)?\)/", $content, $matches)) {

       $languageKeys += $matches[2];
}
```

While the basic regex for detect a string is without escpaing characters:

```
((?<![\\])['"])((?:.(?!(?<![\\])\1))*.?)\1";
```

So notice that in php, due RegExp is inside a string, must escape `\` and `"` to avoid problems